# How can I teleport players in half-block increments?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently working on a map. There is an intro of the map where I want to let players to get teleported half block at a time, following a route to get a preview of the map. If they try to move, they will get teleported back to the route.

How can I make the player be teleported half (or less), not whole blocks at a time?

Comment: What's the _Exact_ issue here? Please be more specific. Also please try to do this yourself **_BEFORE_** you ask here.

Comment: @Alex - It appears the OP is asking how to teleport a player across a set path "fluently" rather than jumping 1 block at a time per teleport.

Comment: Do you really need to do that? Instead, you could just make them walk. Use Barriers and they will have a set path.

Comment: Why not just put them in a minecart on a track?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, use the `/tp` command to tp the Player:

> /tp @a ~ ~ ~+0.5

for teleporting half block in `+z`.

> /tp @a ~ ~ ~-0.5

for -z, and so on - the **first** squigly line is the **x** coordinate, **2nd** is the **y** coordinate and **3rd** one stands for **z**.

For teleporting a Player into **`+x` and `+z`** (or any other coordinates) **at once** a total of 0.5 Blocks, use this (via the Pythagorean stuff):

> /tp a ~+0.35355 ~ ~+0.35355

For teleporting into **`+x`, `+y`, and `+z` at once**, use the following:

> /tp @a ~+0.2887 ~+0.2887 ~+0.2887

- **Each** such command will **move** the Player **exactly** by **0.5** Blocks - for teleporting the Player by 0.5 Blocks in **more** directions, simply combine two commands:
  `/tp @a ~-0.5 ~ ~` + `/tp @a ~ ~+0.5 ~` = `/tp @a ~-0.5 ~+0.5 ~`
- For also **rotating** the Player, use additional syntax:
  `/tp @a X Y Z <Y-Rotation> <X-Rotation>`
  For how to use this syntax, check out the [y-rot and x-rot part of the tp command on Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#tp).
- If you don't want to target **all** Players, use `@p` or [different target selectors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors)
- For further reference, check out [the Wiki article about commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands) (selectors, tp command), [Digminecraft.com article](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/tp_command.php) or find other pages on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=tp%20syntax).

Answer (score 2):

Place a series of armor stands with some scoreboard value, using a 20hz clock, (of repeat blocks) teleport the player to the stand that has a value of zero, the use another block to decrement all of the stands, if you want it to be repeatable, add that number back when you are done.